# Bootstrap Dropdown / HTML Element In Domain Hosted Web-Builder

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, builder, dropdown

I'm likely what you'd consider a complete novice when it comes to web-design and have been putting something fairly basic together using the website builder on godaddy and somewhat of a hack-job of code that I've picked up around the net (hoping all judgement is reserved).

At any rate, I'm trying to make my life easier by using Bootstrap dropdown buttons but I feel like I must be missing something. The site builder allows you to add in an HTML element where you then can enter in .script or whatever as necessary.

The problem arises when the code successfully creates the button; however, the entire HTML element sticks around instead of reverting to alpha (aka going away). Since it will be easier to demonstrate with a visual I've provided the code and a picture below. I've scoured the web for the last couple hours and feel like someone more experienced may be able to help point me in the right direction more expeditiously. Much thanks in advance.

[image: Editor Image]

As you can see here the white box comprises the entire HTML element added by the builder[image: Live site dropdown]

This second image is from the published site. Note that the dropdown cuts off at the edge of the HTML element .If it didn't do that I'd obviously just resize the element but sadly it's not that easy (at least not for me).

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">

<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown List
<span class="caret"></span> 
   </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm marking this resolved as I decided not to use bootstrap and just to code the button myself without using bootstrap as a shortcut. Unfortunately I don't have time to figure this out as I need to publish today. Thanks for your assistance all.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing the https:// in your script file.

Change it to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good catch and thanks for the response. I've updated the code; however, this did not resolve the issue.